# Mapping EF Entity Columns with Translate<T>

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework. I am calling a stored procedure that returns multiple data sets. One of the result sets maps to an entity that I have defined an enumeration for, and have defined a string backing property to receive the result and parse out the enumeration.

```
public class OrderInfo
{
    [Key, Required, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid orderID { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public BillingStatus billingStatus { get; set; }
    [Required, Column("billingStatus")]
    public string billingStatusString
    {
        get { return billingStatus.ToString(); }
        private set { billingStatus = (BillingStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(BillingStatus), value); }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the annotations are ignored when calling db.ObjectContext.Translate( ... ). I get an error message

```
var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[GetOrders]";
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

db.Database.Connection.Open();
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

var orders = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
               .ObjectContext
               .Translate<OrderInfo>(reader, "Orders", MergeOption.AppendOnly)
               .ToList();
reader.NextResult();
```

The mappings defined in the data annotations are not respected, and the Translate method tries to bind to the backing property by its actual name `billingStatusString` rather than its mapped value, `billingStatus`.

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'Orders.OrderInfo'. A member of the type, 'billingStatusString', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

Anyone know why this is, or have a workaround?

Comment: You may have to map the database column to a string property called `billingStatus` and then have another property to retrieve the enum (i.e. `billingStatusEnum`)

Comment: It clearly says the error no `'billingStatusString', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name` ?

Comment: @Sampath, and I expect the attribute `Column("billingStatus"`) that is applied to the `billingStatusString` property should inform EF that the data mapping is from billingStatus => billingStatusString. It obviously doesn't when calling Translate, but I'm looking for some clarity. Why this is a bad idea?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this as I have a very similar issue?